# Rails site not requesting post to facebook permission upon signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api

I searched other threads about this error message and was unable to work out the solution.

I am using the gem 'omniauth-facebook' for authentication (which is working correctly) and gem 'fb_graph' with the purpose of posting to facebook when certain controller actions are hit (creating rows in a model).

In my app settings in facebook developer tools i am currently asking for extended permissions 'publish stream' and 'status update'.  Also, i'm asking for 'publish actions' in User & Friend Permissions.

When i log in for the first time it just signs me in - it does not ask for anything despite saying i want the app to publish.  Any ideas why this is?  I have not added the SDK yet - does this matter / could this be why?

Below is some code

Thanks!

facebook initializer

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, 'my_id', 'my_key', {:scope => 'publish_stream'}
end
```

Action where i'm trying to post after save.  when this action gets hit i get

'OAuthException :: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action'

with the me.feed! line highlighted.

```
def create
@sub_opp = SubOpp.new(sub_opp_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @sub_opp.save
    me = FbGraph::User.me(current_user.oauth_token)
    me.feed!(
    :message => 'Updating via FbGraph',
    )
    format.html { redirect_to sub_opps_url, notice: 'Sub opp was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @sub_opp }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @sub_opp.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
  user.provider = auth.provider
  user.uid = auth.uid
  user.gender = auth.extra.raw_info.gender
  user.email = auth.extra.raw_info.email
  user.name = auth.info.name
  user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
  user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
  user.image_url = auth.info.image
  user.save!
end
```

end
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is odd - this actually works now.  I wonder if I just never restarted my rails s, although I'm quite sure I did.

Everything you see above works for posting to facebook.

In the facebook permission section in your apps facebook developer tools settings, i have the following permissions.

User & Friend Permission: publish_actions
Extended Permission: publish_stream and status_update

Cheers